# Is the norm of projections onto convex sets a convave function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $X\subset R^n$ be a closed convex set, and denote the projections of $x$ onto $X$ as $[x]^+$, i.e., $[x]^+ = argmin_z \{\|x-z\|_2 : z\in X\}$. Let $x\in X,0\neq z\in R^n$ be be given points and define
$f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow R$ as $f(t) = \|[x+tz]^+ - x\|_2$. I wonder whether $f$ is a concave function in $t$? 
I have ploted some figures of $f$ when $X \subset R^2$ are disks, rectangles and triangles, and in these examples $f$ is indeed a concave function. So I want to know whether $f$ is concave in general casess.
Here are some simplifications I made. 
Using some translation we can assume that $x=0\in X$, then $f=\|[tz]^+\|$. And by definition $f$ is concave if the following inequality
$|[(\lambda t_1  + (1-\lambda t_2)) z]^+\|\geq \lambda\|t_1z]^+\|+(1-\lambda)\|[t_2 z]^+\|$
holds for all $t_1,t_2\geq 0$ and $\lambda\in [0,1]$.
But I don't how to preceed then. 
And I know $f(t)/t$ is a monotonically nonincreasing, which may be useful for the proof.
Another closed relation problem is that whether $g:R^n \rightarrow R$ defined as $g(y):=\|[y]^+\|$ is concave. And if $g$ is concave then automatically $f$ will be concave.
Could anyone please share some thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, and in general I don't know if an answer is known. I can recall the following cases in which $f$ is actually *convex*:

- if $X$ is a vector subspace, then the projection operator $[\cdot]^+$ is linear, so $f$ is convex as an affine transformation of $\|\cdot\|_2$.
- if $X$ is a cone, then a standard result (e.g., in Bauschke/Combettes' book on Convex Analysis and monotone operator theory in Hilbert spaces) states that $g$ is convex, so $f$ would retain convexity if $x=0$ as well.

Comment: I am sorry i have made a mistake in the definition of $f$, which has been corrected now. So $f$ can be either concave or convex? If you let $X$ be the unit disk and $x=(0,1)^T, z = (1,0)^T$, then $f(t)=\|[x+tz]^+-x\|$ will be concave. In your first example $f$ is in fact linear?

Comment: For the cone $X=\{(x,y,z)\in R^3:x^2+y^2\leq z^2\}$, the figure of $f$ suggests that $f(t)=\|[x+tz]^+-x\|$ is also linear in t. So it might be that in your two examples $f$ are both linear, which are also concave.

Comment: For the first setting, the projection is linear but $\|\cdot\|$ is strongly convex (nonlinear), so in the general setting $f$ is guaranteed convex but potentially nonlinear (except for some basic sesttings like $X=\{0\}$.)

Comment: The conic and unit ball examples do not look linear to me. Could you please explain further?

Comment: The function $g(x)=\|[x]^+\|$ may be convex or strongly convex. But $f:[0,+\infty) \rightarrow R,f(t) = \|[x+t*z]^+-z\|$, at least in these two examples, is linear. I dont know how to prove it, but the graph of $f$ is cleary linear.

Comment: And the convexity of $\|[x]^+\|$ does not impliy the convexity of  $f(t) = \|[x+t*z]^+ - z\|$, it implies the convixity of $\|[x+t*z]^+\|$.

Comment: @Yunfei could you please provide the graph of the examples? I'm having trouble seeing this as linear.

Comment: @Yunfei correct, it would not imply convexity of $\|[x+tz]^+-z\|$, but your question states that $f(x)=\|[x+tz]^+-\mathbf{x}\|$, and my answer states that it would only imply convexity in the case where $x=0$.